# How to Migrate Posts and Pages from Crafts CMS to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have a website in Crafts CMS and having 100+ posts and pages. I am creating new wordpress website where I need to copy all the posts and pages from Crafts cms to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/craftcms/element-api to create a dump of your content and use a wordpress import process to add the old content.